# CloudFormation SQS Queue Redrive policy dependency on a DLQ created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cloudformation

I'm using a CloudFormation template to create a stack for SQS. I have one SQS queue set with a dependency to another SQS queue used as a DLQ. When I create the stack I get this error:

```
Value {"deadLetterTargetArn":"arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx:services-abc-dlq","maxReceiveCount":"10"} for parameter RedrivePolicy is invalid. Reason: Dead letter target does not exist.
```

How do I set a redrive policy to wait for DLQ to finish being created?

Here's the pertinent information from my template:

```
"Resources": {
    "queueservicesdlqevents": {
      "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
      "Properties": {
        "DelaySeconds": "0",
        "MaximumMessageSize": "262144",
        "MessageRetentionPeriod": "345600",
        "QueueName": "services-abc-dlq",
        "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds": "0",
        "VisibilityTimeout": "30"
      }
    },
    "queueservicesevents": {
      "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
      "Properties": {
        "DelaySeconds": "0",
        "MaximumMessageSize": "262144",
        "MessageRetentionPeriod": "345600",
        "QueueName": "services-abc-events",
        "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds": "20",
        "VisibilityTimeout": "30",
        "RedrivePolicy": {
          "deadLetterTargetArn" : "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:xxxxxx:services-abc-dlq",
          "maxReceiveCount" : 10
        }
      }
    },
```

Just to add, making a "Ref" to other queue doesn't work because dlqtargetArn expects a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Just to add, making a "Ref" to other queue doesn't work because dlqtargetArn expects a string.

[Ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) only provides the (default) value of an [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) resource, but you can get the value of other attributes of a resource by means of [Fn::GetAtt](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html) as follows:

```
"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "logicalNameOfResource", "attributeName" ]
```

That is, as per section *Return Values* within [AWS::SQS::Queue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html#aws-sqs-queue-redrive), the ARN of the dead letter queue at hand is available via:

```
"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "queueservicesdlqevents", "Arn" ]
```

Once you reference the actual ARN from the dependent resource, CloudFormation will ensure that the dependency is created first so that the dead letter target `queueservicesdlqevents` already exists when you create the `queueservicesevents` queue.

Comment: short syntax `!GetAtt queueservicesdlqevents.Arn`